# Python OpenCv: how to display an image on a window

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, camera, raspberry-pi, photo

I wrote a code that shoot a photo and save it, the image successly should be displayed on a window.
But the window not contain the image and appear a gray screen.
Below I've dropped a part of the code.

```
cam = PiCamera(resolution = (640,480))
cam.start_preview()

cam.capture('foto 1.jpg') 
cam.stop_preview()          
img = cv2.imread('foto 1.jpg')

cv2.imshow('image',img) 
if(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27):
    break
```

Comment: After cam.start_preview and before cam.capture, try adding sleep(2).  The documentation states the camera needs a warmup time.  https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes1.html

Comment: thank, but i solve it, i forgot the waitkey...